# ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00201: identifier exception

Tags: c#, oracle

Below are the procedure and the code. Even though the signature is same, i am getting the error ORA-06550

procedure prc_MediaProSchExport(c_ResultSet       OUT t_Cursor,
                                vChas         IN Varchar2,
                                vTXS          IN Date,
                                vTXE          IN Date,
                                vSch          IN Varchar2
                                )

---

```
        OracleParameter oParam = new OracleParameter("c_ResultSet", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
        oParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        parameterList[0] = oParam;

        OracleParameter oParam1 = new OracleParameter("VARI", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
        oParam1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterList[1] = oParam1;

        DateTime gmtDateTime = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());


        OracleParameter oParam2 = new OracleParameter(gmtDateTime.ToString(), OracleDbType.Date);
        oParam2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterList[2] = oParam2;

        OracleParameter oParam3 = new OracleParameter(gmtDateTime.ToString(), OracleDbType.Date);
        oParam3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterList[3] = oParam3;

        OracleParameter oParam4 = new OracleParameter("ABCD", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
        oParam4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterList[4] = oParam4;
```

Comment: The "PLS-00201: identifier exception" error message could also point to a misspelling of your procedure name itself when you call it. Can you please add the procedure call as well as the full error stack in your code example above.

Comment: Got the answer.It should be parameter name not the value.  gmtDateTime.ToString() shouldnt be.